# It is possible to reinterpret equivalence relations and partial orders as operations of some arity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, universal-algebra

I have a question going on in my head for some days. To better write it, I need to know if the axiomatizations of partial orders, equivalence relations and so on may be rewritten in terms of I-ary operations (I may be also an infinite index set). I'm not an expert on universal algebra, so I ask for a detailed answer and for references, if any.

Comment: What kinds of axioms are allowed? Are you only permitting only equational identities (e.g. first-order statements of the form $\forall x_1 \forall x_2 ... \forall x_n (T_1 = T_2)$ where $T_1, T_2$ are terms with free variables $x_1, ..., x_n$), or do you permit any sort of axioms (e.g. something like the field axiom $\forall x (\forall y (x \cdot y \neq 1) \iff x = 0))$)?

Comment: The usual axiomatization of an equivalence relation, i.e. reflexivity, transitivity and symmetry

Comment: No, I meant what axioms are you allowing on the operators that are supposed to describe the partial order?

Comment: Any sort of axioms is accepted. Certainly, if it is possible to use online equational identities, it would be better. Please, see also the comments under Eric's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given a reflexive relation $R$ on a set $S$, you can define a binary operation $*$ on $S$ by $a*b=a$ if $aRb$ and $a*b=b$ otherwise, and conversely you can recover $R$ from $*$ (given that $R$ is known to be reflexive).  So, you could rewrite all the axioms for a partial order or an equivalence relation in terms of the corresponding binary operation $*$.

(If you allow operations that are not total, you can drop the requirement that $R$ is reflexive by saying $a*b=a$ if $aRb$ and otherwise $a*b$ is undefined.  With total operations, though, there is no way to encode arbitrary relations on a set in general, for the simple reason that a singleton set has only one total operation of any arity but has two different relations.)

Comment: Ok. In the hypothesis that R is an equivalence relation, how to describe reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity in terms of operations of some arity? In fact, from your answer it seems more convenient to use partial operations in this case. Is it possible to use a description using only total operations, since there is only an equivalence relation on singletons?

Comment: Same question for posets and for the binary relation on $P(\Omega)$ (the powerset of $\Omega$) satisfying:  1) $A \subseteq B \implies A \mathcal{R} B$; 2) $\mathcal{R}$ is transitive;  3) $A \mathcal{R} B$ if and only if $\forall a \in A \,\, \{a\} \mathcal{R} B$. In both cases there is only a relation on a singleton set. Can you also provide an example where partial operation is only allowed? I thought of transitive relations. Note moreover that these relations admit a "closure" (namely intersection of relations containing a given one). Can I use operation to describe members of the closure?